# How to print the key values of a B tree in a tree fashion in simplest way?

Tags: java, tree, output, b-tree

```
public void print ( BNode n )  
    {           
        for ( int k = temp ; k>=0 ; k=k-30 ) // temp = 300
        {
            System.out.print("     ");
        }            
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < n.count ; i++ ) 
        {
            System.out.print ( n.getValue(i) + " " ) ;    
        }                             
        if ( !n.leaf ) 
        {
               System.out.println ("") ;                
            for ( int j = 0; j <= n.count ; j++ )
            {                 
                temp = --temp ;                   
                if ( n.getChild(j) != null ) 
                {                                         
                    print( n.getChild(j) ) ;                     
                }                                
            }                
        }        
    }
```

I am trying to print the key values of a B tree in Pre Order fashion like the B tree renderer given [here](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/1158559/btree-figure9.png).

I don't want to print the arrows but want some good spacing . I have given a try in my code but I don't think its the right way .

What can I do to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print tab character '\t' $currentLevel number of times.